# Teradata- Summing column values by row without typing in the column name

Tags: sql, sum, multiple-columns, teradata

So I have like 100 Columns that has values and I need to sum it all up for each row in teradata. Is there a way where I can Sum it all up, without having to type down each and every column name ?

I want the results to be

```
SELECT  CustID,(Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+.....................Col100)

FROM    CustomerTable
```

Can I do this without typing the column names. I know * will sum all the rows. Similarly is there a way where I can sum the values in each column of the same row?

Comment: You request is an indication to bad design.

Comment: Nope. In SQL you have to type out what you want to sum. You could... create a proc that selects from `dbc.columns` for that table/database table, open a cursor, loop through the records and build a dynamic SQL statement using the results, then execute it. But... that would probably be 1000x times harder than just writing up a quick sql statement to sum up the 100 columns.

Comment: Also, when I'm stuck with a tedious task like this, I just dump the columns name out to Notepad and find and replace the commas to plusses. It's not much work.

Comment: I understand it is bad design. DB admin has been notified. But I still need to get the report out. The notepad option sounds like the easiest one for now. Thank you guys :-)

Answer (score 2):

This might ease you work

```
select      '+ ' || columnname 

from        dbc.columnsv

where       databasename    = '{your database}'
        and tablename       = '{your table}'
        and columnname      not in ('CustID',...,...)

order by    columnid
```